# Why does this python recursive function return the values in the order that it does?

Tags: python, recursion

Looking at the recursive function below, when run, it prints out;

Recursion Example Results

```
1
3
6
10
15
21
```

Why is does it start with 1 and move up to 21, surely it should be the other way around?

```
def tri_recursion(k):
  if(k>0):
    result = k+tri_recursion(k-1)
    print(result)
  else:
    result = 0
  return result

print("\n\nRecursion Example Results")
tri_recursion(6)
```

Please note the example above is from w3schools

Comment: Why do you think it should be the other way round? The call to `print(result)` is after the recursive call

Answer (score 1):

Stripping away the implementation, the recursive definition can be written mathematically as:

```
f(k) = k + f(k-1)
```

To put the core of this in actual words, *the value of the `k`'th step requires the value of the `k-1`'th step*.

So to complete the 2nd step (which prints 3), the 1st step must be completed first (which prints 1). Likewise, to complete the 3rd step (which prints 6), the 2nd and thus the 1st step must be completed first.

Or generally, to compute `f(k)` one must first compute `f(k-1)`, for which one must first compute `f(k-2)`, ..., for which one must first compute `f(1)`.

In the actual implementation, observe how the preceding value `tri_recursion(k-1)` is computed completely before the current value `k + tri_recursion(k-1)`:

```py
    #            v completely computes f(k-1)
    result = k + tri_recursion(k-1)
    # print *after* having recursed to f(k-1), f(k-2), ..., f(1)
    print(result)
```

Comment: This is helpful, the recursion must be complete before moving on to the print?

Comment: Exactly. Evaluating ``k + tri_recursion(k-1)`` for ``tri_recursion(k)`` requires ``tri_recursion(k-1)`` to be completed before using its value.

Answer (score 0):

```
def tri_recursion(k):
  if(k>0):
    result = k+tri_recursion(k-1)
    print(result)
  else:
    result = 0
  return result

print("\n\nRecursion Example Results")
tri_recursion(6)
```

In the above code provided you have given the print statement after the function call as cleared by [@UholySheep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2878796/unholysheep)

so basically the recursion will go on till the `k` variable is greater than zero.

but at the instance of the `k` becoming zero the else condition is executed and the return of zero is given to recursive parent.

where, `result = 1 + 0` becomes one.
and print statement gives answer 1.

Answer (score 0):

There does not seem to be any reason for the other way round since `print(result)` is written after the recursive call to function. This line `result = k+tri_recursion(k-1)` will finish once we have `k=0` and at that moment we get `result=1`(k=1 and recursive function returns 0 i.e., 1+0=1). In stack we have result values as [1,3,6,10,15,21] and it prints from head and hence the above sequence completely makes sense.